# How to debug Google Fit data?

Tags: google-api, google-fit

I've been sending a ton of data to the Google Fit API for a workout being performed by the user, but none of the data is showing up in the app anywhere and I'm not sure how to tell what is wrong.  The data is accepted by the API, but none of it is showing up in the user's profile in the app.  Does anyone have a strategy for telling if all the different data sets are being connected correctly?

I've been trying for over a year to find someone who works with the Google Fit team to help answer some questions, but I have not been able to find anyone.  It seems like the app only wants to show steps, so all the actual workout data that I'm sending it might just be ignored?

Comment: Do you see your uploaded data in data studio?

Comment: @Kundan, I do not see the data but I will spend some more time digging in there.

Comment: https://youtu.be/XmUJ602bExw

Comment: did you manage to get the data in data studio?

Comment: Thanks for the video! I'm working through it right now trying to figure out what's happening.